# Python: How to check number between a dictionary

Tags: python

I have created a tuple using the following function. when the code runs the tuple created looks like `(0,[1,4,0]),(0,[2,5,0])`. The numbers that should be checked before the counter is incremented are 1 and 4 from the first tuple or 2 and 5 on the second tuple. For some reason, I don't know why the counter will display the same value for all. It supposed to be different numbers.

```
listA=[1,2,3,4,56,7,87,6]
listB=[4,5,6,7,8,7,8,7]
def myFunction(data):
   counter=0
   myList=[]

   for i,a in enumerate(zip(listA, listB)):
       myList.append((i, [a[0], a[1], counter]))

   myDictionary=dict(myList)

   for number in data:
       for key in myDictionary.keys():
            if (myDictionary[key][0] < number <= myDictionary[key][1]):
                counter = counter+1
```

The counter is supposed to increment when the numbers in myDictionary is between the numbers

Comment: What are you passing in for the argument `data`, and what value do you expect `counter` to end up on for it?

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing the counter primitive. Rather increment the counter in the dictionary.

```
listA=[1,2,3,4,56,7,87,6]
listB=[4,5,6,7,8,7,8,7]
def myFunction(data):
   counter=0
   myList=[]

   for i,a in enumerate(zip(listA, listB)):
       myList.append((i, [a[0], a[1], counter]))

   myDictionary=dict(myList)

   for number in data:
       for key in myDictionary.keys():
            if (myDictionary[key][0] < number <= myDictionary[key][1]):
                myDictionary[key][2] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you expect this line:

```
myList.append((i, [a[0], a[1], counter]))
```

to put a different `counter` in each item - but you haven't changed counter at this point, and it will always be 0 here. When you later increment it, that only changes the function variable `counter`, and not the elements of any of the tuples. So I think you want to calculate a new counter each time around this loop, and put that in to each tuple:

```
for i,a in enumerate(zip(ListA, ListB)):
   counter = 0
   for number in data:
      if a[0] < number <= a[1]:
         counter += 1
   myList.append((i, a[0], a[1], counter))
```

---

Note that you can simplify this quite a bit. First, you're building a list that only exists to turn into a dictionary - you can just build the dictionary directly:

```
myDictionary = {}

for i,a in enumerate(zip(ListA, ListB)):
   counter = 0
   for number in data:
      if a[0] < number <= a[1]:
         counter += 1
   myDictionary[i] = a[0], a[1], counter
```

But, since the keys of this dict will always just be the numbers from 0 up to the number of items in it, you might consider just using a slightly simpler list than you were before (which lets you avoid playing with indexes, and skip the call to enumerate):

```
myList = []
for a in zip(ListA, ListB):
   counter = 0
   for number in data:
      if a[0] < number <= a[1]:
         counter += 1
   myList.append((a[0], a[1], counter))
```

Secondly, you can use the builtin `sum` and a generator expression to calculate your counter for you:

```
for a in zip(ListA, ListB):
   counter = sum(a[0] < number <= a[1] for number in data)
   myList.append((a[0], a[1], counter))
```

Comment: You dropped some necessary parentheses in the `append` call for the last two versions of the code.